# Netsuite: "CASE WHEN" formula on in Workflow Action

Tags: workflow, formula, netsuite

I have a question about Formulas in a Workflow action. I want to send to user error action if the conditions are right.

I have that on the formula field:

`CASE WHEN {startdate} <= TO_DATE(TO_CHAR({custbody_swe_from_contract.custrecord_contracts_end_date}, 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'dd/mm/yyyy') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`

also tried different options:

`(CASE WHEN {startdate} <= TO_DATE(TO_CHAR({custbody_swe_from_contract.custrecord_contracts_end_date}, 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'dd/mm/yyyy') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1`

and

`(CASE WHEN {startdate} <= TO_DATE(TO_CHAR({custbody_swe_from_contract.custrecord_contracts_end_date}, 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'dd/mm/yyyy') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1`

But when the Workflows launch i got these error:

`Error while evaluating condition: ERROR: Invalid Expression`

I don't know why, but on a Saved Search works whell with first option.

Thanks!

Comment: Try deconstructing the formula one by one in the workflow and see if the data is being sourced correctly. See if you get any value when you output {custbody_swe_from_contract.custrecord_contracts_end_date} by itself

Comment: I tried this on the formula: 

{startdate} = {startdate} OK

///

{custbody_swe_from_contract.custrecord_contracts_end_date} = {custbody_swe_from_contract.custrecord_contracts_end_date} OK

///

{startdate} <= {custbody_swe_from_contract.custrecord_contracts_end_date} BAD EXPRESSION

///

CASE WHEN {startdate} <= {custbody_swe_from_contract.custrecord_contracts_end_date} THEN 1 ELSE 0 END =  BAD EXPRESSION

Comment: From NS: Its not compatible to call field from other record in a WF formulas. Can't do that: {custbody_swe_from_contract.custrecord_contracts_end_date}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response from Netsuite:

Comparing 'startdate' field with 'custrecord_contracts_end_date' from another record. This is not supported yet unfortunately. We suggest create a custom field and source the field value, then compare 'startdate' with the custom field.